# Starting global session to all pages

Tags: php, session

How can i start a session in PHP which will be global to all my pages. I don't have access to the `php.ini` file. So `session.auto_start = 0` in my `php.ini` will not be a solution for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` is a global.

Start it off by calling `session_start()` before any output.

Comment: Thanks For the Answers, but my problem is, when i start the session on my first page, i cant access the session values on the other pages. To be more specific when i debug using eclipse, i can see the session started in the first page and it gets resetted to empty when i use header(..); on my page to forward to other pages. I dont why it is resetted, when i am not calling session_destroy();

Comment: @tsegay You should put you session_start() on all pages where you intend to use sessions.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
```

Place this at the top of your pages and it will start a session.  You can access it and set its variables with $_SESSION['somevalue'].  Also you can name the session using session_name("some name");

Answer (score 0):

If you want all pages to automagically have a `session_start()`, without actually writing the code, you're pretty much stuck with ini-settings. It is very well possible that although you cannot alter `php.ini` in a shared environment (proper hosters do offer a custom ini IMO), that you can just add the `php_flag session.autostart = 1` to an .htaccess file in the root.

Comment: Thanks For the Answers, but my problem is, when i start the session on my first page, i cant access the session values on the other pages. To be more specific when i debug using eclipse, i can see the session started in the first page and it gets resetted to empty when i use header(..); on my page to forward to other pages.

I dont why it is resetted, when i am not calling session_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

Nothing bad in starting a session with session_start() - everyone doing that.
Don't you have some config file already, which being included into every script on the site? If yes - why not to put session_start there? If not - you have to think of having one.